# Calling An Array From Another Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Still attempting to grasp iPhone programming and have come across a problem. I have an NSMutableArray within a class that stores the text value of each cell that is chosen/clicked on. In another view, i'd like to populate another table view with the array that was formed earlier. However, how do I go about accessing this array (which is a property in View1) from View2.

Will the array still be filled with the strings if I go to another view? Or does this require a sqLite DB or something along those lines to maintain persistence?

I have tried initializing another NSMutableArray with the contents of the array from View1, but this doesn't seem to be right:

```
//View2.h
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *savedExercise = [Create workout];
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create view2 from view1, a common pattern is to create another init method, so when you create view 2, you would call

```
view2 = [[View2 alloc] initWithData:data];
```

where data is your array.

In View2, you would have

```
-(id)initWithData:(NSArray*)_data{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        dataProperty = _data;
    }
    return self;
}
```

where dataProperty is a property on View2.

Answer (score 0):

You should create getter (and if needed also setter) methods for the instance variable "workout" in View1. To do this you can use the @property functionality of Objective-C.

Then access the instance of View1 in View2 to get the pointer to `workout`.

A better method is creating a singleton "Data Manager" and access it through a sharedInstance-method (as we discussed in chat). You data is then managed completely by that instance and can be accessed any time at any part of your App by "talking" to that sharedInstance.

Comment: I was under the impression getter and setters were pre-written if you synthesized the array? Also, when you say access View1 in View2 are you talking about importing it?

Comment: Yes exactly: setter and getter methods will be set by declaring "workout" as a property and synthesizing it afterwards. By accessing View1 in View2, I meant getting the pointer to it. It depends on how you built up the view structure.

Comment: What's the syntax for calling a getter method in another class/view?

Comment: It's that simple: [view1 workout], where view1 has to be the pointer to the instance of View1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I went the wrong way about building the view structure. I have a view controller, that serves as my main menu, in which if you click on one button, one view (represented by a different class/view controller) is pushed on top of that view. So I have three different view controllers (main menu, two seperate views). Where should I create the instance of View1? Within View2? Or the app delegate?

Comment: Maybe you try to completely separate your data from your view, which should be the main philosophy behind the MVC. To achieve this, I would recommend at least to create a shared instance of a "data manager", which holds the relevant information and let the view instances access it via the shared object class method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9877/discussion-between-topchef-and-septi)

Answer (score 0):

If your app is iOS 5 specific and you go from View1 to View2, you can use segues and prepareForSegue to pass the data.

You would call the segue with `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and then in your prepareForSegue method you could do something like: `[segue.destinationViewController setArray:###pass array here###]` You just need a property in your View2Controller's header that has a setter called setArray (or whatever you want to name it).